# How do I dynamically add an after filter to Rails from within a controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, metaprogramming

Each time a user accesses a page in my Rails app, the database needs to send them a Thingy. When the database runs out of Thingies, it has to do some expensive processing to generate more. I want to add a controller filter dynamically to generate the thingies *after* the response has been sent to the user so that it doesn't affect page load times. Here's what my controller looks like:

```
class ThingyController < ApplicationController

  def get_a_thingy
    if Thingy.count <= 5 
      # Only five thingies left! we need to generate some more. 
      # I want to dynamically send a block to an after_filter: here to  
      # generate thingies after the controller sends the response  
      # because generating thingies is really slow
    end

    # Pop the first thingy from the database and return
    thingy = Thingy.first
    thingy.delete 
    return thingy.content
  end
```

What can I add in the `get_a_thingy` function to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You may try some background processing tools( https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs check this), cause I'm not sure you can do it inside a request handler.

You may also try to return all the content to user (via smthing like http streaming) and only then make your heavy things.

Comment: You're right. I just tested it by adding `sleep 5` in an `after_filter` - it does indeed wait for all the filters to finish before sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `if` statement that checks for the number of thingies in your `after_filter` code:

```
class ThingyController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :generate_new_thingies

  def get_a_thingy
    thingy = Thingy.first
    thingy.delete
    return thingy.content
  end

  def generate_new_thingies
    if Thingy.count <= 5
      # Generate thingies
    end
  end
end
```

Does using `after_filter` really prevent long page loads? It may be better to have a look at something like [Delayed Job](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job) or [Whenever](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby).

Comment: I was surprised too but `thingy.delete` seems to work. I had a feeling I'd have to add the filter using the usual way - is there a way I can get the filter to run only if the action is "get_a_thingy"? I'd rather not have to query Thingy.count for every action the controller performs. Thanks!

Comment: haha nevermind.. answered my own question: `after_filter :generate_new_thingies, :only => :get_a_thingy`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best idea will by a gem like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) there is also a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised) for it.

Delayed job is an asynchronously priority queue system.

- Install and setup the delayed_job. It is pretty well documented on the github [page](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).
- Start the worker with `rake jobs:work`
- Now simply change your code to use the delay job by adding the `.delay` method

```rb
class ThingyController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :generate_thingies
  .
  .
  .
  def generate_thingies
    if Thingy.count <= 5
      #change
      Thingy.generate_thingies
      #to
      Thingy.delay.generate_thingies
    end
  end
end
```

NOTE: This is a small tutorial and I left out a some of things that you will need to get it working. I recommend you to check the Github page for a full documentation.